# Точность данных при математических операциях в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Столкнулся с проблемой точности данных в mysql: при выполнении математических операций нужно получать результат строго с двумя точками после запятой, казалось бы для этого идеально подходят DECIMAL(M,N) или NUMERIC(M,N), однако, при выполнении умножения на десятичное число, количество знаков после запятой увеличивается на то количество знаков, которое было у второго множителя. Пример:
В табличке table в колонке column с типом данных DECIMAL(12,2) хранятся данные:

```
Column
---------
114580.00
104635.00
113475.00
114070.00
148707.50
101277.50
```

После умножения данных в этой колонке на 0.875 получаю:

```
Column
------------
111486.34000
101809.85500
110411.17500
110990.11000
144692.39750
98543.00750
```

Как получить результат с округлением до двух точек после запятой после умножения?

```
Column
---------
111486.34
101809.85
110411.17
110990.11
144692.40
98543.08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно воспользоватся функцией [ROUND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Пример:

```
SET @t1=114580.00;
SET @t2=0.875;
SET @t3 := @t1 * @t2;
SELECT @t1, @t2, ROUND(@t3, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Выполните преобразование типа результата: CAST(X AS NUMERIC(8,2))